# c++ looping statement on package pricing

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a loop statement to determine the prices according to their respective packages but I can't seem to get a grasp of the `do` and `while` statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double W_adult=47.90, W_child=41.50, W_senior=35.40, A_adult=25.90, A_child=20.50, A_senior=15.40, P_adult=15.90, P_child=12.50, P_senior=10.40;
    double totaladult,totalchild,totalsenior, total;
    int noadult,nochild,nosenior;
    char option;
    //char choice = 'y'; looping choice

    cout<<"WELCOME TO WAS LOST WORLD THEME PARK\n\n"<<endl;
    cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*";
    cout<<"\nPackage name \t | ADULT\t | CHILD\t | SENIOR CITIZEN"<<endl;
    cout<<"|A| Water Park\t | 47.90\t | 41.50\t | 35.40"<<endl;
    cout<<"|B| Am. Park\t | 25.90 \t | 20.50 \t | 15.40"<<endl;
    cout<<"|C| Pet. Zoo\t | 15.90\t | 12.50\t | 10.40"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*";

    cout<<"\nChoose your package A/B/C: "<<endl;
    cin>>option;

    cout<<"Enter the no of adult: "<<endl;
    cin>>noadult;
    cout<<"Enter the no of child: "<<endl;
    cin>>nochild;
    cout<<"Enter the no of senior citizen: "<<endl;
    cin>>nosenior;

    switch(option)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            totaladult=W_adult*noadult;
            totalchild=W_child*nochild;
            totalsenior=W_senior*nosenior;

        break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            totaladult=A_adult*noadult;
            totalchild=A_child*nochild;
            totalsenior=A_senior*nosenior;

        break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            totaladult=P_adult*noadult;
            totalchild=P_child*nochild;
            totalsenior=P_senior*nosenior;

        break;
    }

    cout<<"Total no of adult is: "<<noadult<<endl;
    cout<<"Total no of child is: "<<nochild<<endl;
    cout<<"Total no of senior citizen is: "<<nosenior<<endl;
    cout<<"Total price of adult is: "<<totaladult<<endl;
    cout<<"Total price of child is: "<<totalchild<<endl;
    cout<<"Total price of senior citizen is: "<<totalsenior<<endl;
    cout<<"The total price is: "<<totaladult+totalchild+totalsenior<<endl;

    return 0;       
}
```

Is there something else I'm missing here? Currently it only calculates the price of one category. I would like know where should I include the loop statements.

Comment: You need a plan. Coding without a plan is almost always a bad idea. Write down what you need the program to do on paper. Normally I'd organize that list by what has to happen in what order, but in this case I think drawing a diagram might help more because you can add lines to better describe the flow of one step to the next. Somewhere in that drawing you'll find you need a line that goes back to the beginning. That's where the loop is. You may find a `do`/`while` loop fits well here.

Comment: Just a recommendation: Don't use doubles for pricings and calculations. Even `0.40` cannot be represented exactly in double, as it is periodic in binary representation. Instead, you might do all calculations in cents and just format the final output appropriately.

Comment: You additionally might use the price constants to print the pricing table, this way don't repeat 'magic numbers' and don't have to adjust twice if you need to change a price.

Answer (score 0):

you should add an option to quit, and while loop as long as the user keep selecting packages:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const double W_adult=47.90, W_child=41.50, W_senior=35.40, A_adult=25.90, A_child=20.50, A_senior=15.40, P_adult=15.90, P_child=12.50, P_senior=10.40;
double totaladult = 0,totalchild = 0,totalsenior = 0, total = 0;
int noadult = 0,nochild = 0,nosenior = 0;
char option;
bool run = true;
//char choice = 'y'; looping choice

cout<<"WELCOME TO WAS LOST WORLD THEME PARK\n\n"<<endl;
cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*";
cout<<"\nPackage name \t | ADULT\t | CHILD\t | SENIOR CITIZEN"<<endl;
cout<<"|A| Water Park\t | 47.90\t | 41.50\t | 35.40"<<endl;
cout<<"|B| Am. Park\t | 25.90 \t | 20.50 \t | 15.40"<<endl;
cout<<"|C| Pet. Zoo\t | 15.90\t | 12.50\t | 10.40"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*";

while(run)
{
cout<<"\nChoose your package A/B/C --- or Q to quit: "<<endl;
cin>>option;


cout<<"Enter the no of adult: "<<endl;
cin>>noadult;
cout<<"Enter the no of child: "<<endl;
cin>>nochild;
cout<<"Enter the no of senior citizen: "<<endl;
cin>>nosenior;

switch(option)
{
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        totaladult+=W_adult*noadult;
        totalchild+=W_child*nochild;
        totalsenior+=W_senior*nosenior;

    break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        totaladult+=A_adult*noadult;
        totalchild+=A_child*nochild;
        totalsenior+=A_senior*nosenior;

    break;

    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        totaladult+=P_adult*noadult;
        totalchild+=P_child*nochild;
        totalsenior+=P_senior*nosenior;
        break;

        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            run = false;
            break;

        default:
            // do nothing
            break;

    break;
}

cout<<"Total no of adult is: "<<noadult<<endl;
cout<<"Total no of child is: "<<nochild<<endl;
cout<<"Total no of senior citizen is: "<<nosenior<<endl;
cout<<"Total price of adult is: "<<totaladult<<endl;
cout<<"Total price of child is: "<<totalchild<<endl;
cout<<"Total price of senior citizen is: "<<totalsenior<<endl;
cout<<"The total price is: "<<totaladult+totalchild+totalsenior<<endl;
}
return 0;   

}
```

Comment: I recommend not to quit the loop on invalid input; user accidentally typing bad key will force her/him to restart entire programme. Worse: you *now* invoke undefined behaviour: You replaced `=` with `+=` but forgot the now necessary initialisation of the totals.

Comment: @Aconcagua, Thanks for your feedback. I agree to both comments on exit condition from the loop, as well as missing init for the total. I gave the code sample only to show the concept; by all means I did not plan to provide 0 bug, production quality code.

Comment: *'I did not plan to provide 0 bug [...] code'* – the point is: introducing a new bug that did not exist before is critical for the question author, especially as the missing initialisation is harder to spot. She/he likely runs into such error and again wonders why code is not working, or even worse, seems to work in debug, but not in release mode. If you want to further improve your answer: Highlight the additionally necessary changes with some comment (so that QA catches better) and explaining why this change now is necessary (difference between `=` and `+=`, etc).

Comment: The exiting, on the other hand, is *rather* just cosmetics. But you can hint QA or other readers to what is good practice – or head them into the opposite direction. If we are on that: Instead of not doing anything, you might hint to better practice of outputting some error message (just as comment like `// some appropriate error handling` or `[...] message` is far enough..).

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks again for your valuable comments. I have corrected my code.